# how to create a user defined function in awk

Tags: awk

Here I have written an awk script to calculate yrs months and days from date of birth to the current date (here we take month means 30days, so 
maketime and systime i am not using)

My problem is how to create a user defined function to return the yrs, months and days with my code. The dob is in dd/mm/yyyy format.

```
 d=`date +%d`
 m=`date +%m`
 y=`date +%Y`
 awk -v curd="$d" -v curm="$m" -v cury="$y" '{
           doby=substr($0,10,4)+0
           dobm=substr($0,14,2)+0
           dobd=substr($0,16,2)+0
                 if(curd < dobd){
                 days = curd+30-dobd
                 mths = curm - 1 - dobm
                 yrs  = cury-doby
                 curm = curm - 1
                 if(curm<dobm){
                 mths = curm+12-dobm
                 yrs  = cury-1-doby
                 }
               }else{
           days = curd-dobd
           mths = curm-dobm
           yrs  = cury-doby
           if(curm<dobm){
           mths = curm+12-dobm
           yrs  = cury-1-doby
         }
        }
      printf"%-30s %2s %2s %2s\n",$0,yrs,mths,days
      }' x1
```

Thank you.

Comment: If the date of birth is really formatted `dd/mm/yyyy`, then your `substr` calls will not produce the expected output.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `split` function instead of  `substr`: `split($0,Date,"/")`

Comment: Your function should have two parameters (two dates in format dd/mm/yyyy) or six parameters. Then your function has only to substract value pairs and make some corrections.

Comment: Of course! I gave actual positions of the dob string in my file. It worked. As you told it needs 6 parameters. but i am not much familiar with awk.. i use it as and when needed. You mean six parameters cury,curm,curd and same sas dob too.